# Активити не может прочитать строку

Tags: android

Код активити:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        TextView tv;
        CharSequence cs;
        String str;

        // Using the getString() conevenience method, retrieve a string
        // resource that happens to have style information.  Note the use of
        // CharSequence instead of String so we don't lose the style info.
        cs = getText(R.string.action_2);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.action_2);
        tv.setText(cs);

    }
}
```

Приложение вылетает с такой ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.app.szpp/ru.app.szpp.Activity2}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (807 ... 1489) ends beyond length 16
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (807 ... 1489) ends beyond length 16
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:472)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:189)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:178)
at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:60)
at android.content.res.StringBlock.applyStyles(StringBlock.java:183)
at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:134)
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.getStringFromPool(ApkAssets.java:136)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:480)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java:496)
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:355)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:574)
at ru.app.szpp.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7200)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7191)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
... 11 more
```

Ресурс R.string.action_2 оформлен нормально вроде...
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вам точно getText а не getString нужен?

Comment: А какая разница в общем то? Загрузить текст из указанной строки вроде бы получается... Кроме того, есть аналогичное активити, только грузится другая строка, там все работает. Исправил на getString, эффект тот же...

Comment: Вообще да, в принципе все отличие что getString CharSequence к String приводит. По идее должно быть нормально все. Вообще выглядит как будто что то со строкой.

Comment: И еще вопрос, зачем вы вызываете два раза super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);?

Comment: Это мне неизвестно )) убрал один из вызовов super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) Ошибка та же самая

Comment: при выводе текста в формате `Char Sequence` есть [много ограничений на содержимое строки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) . В вашей строке нет запрещенных символов\форматирования и прочего из ограничений?

Comment: Действительно, в строке были запрещенные символы и она оказалась длиннее допустимого. Самое интересное, что проблема обнаружилась после обновления Студии, я просто пересобрал тот же файл, что раньше работал без проблем и получил вышеуказанную проблему. То есть новая Студия заведомо менее функциональная

Comment: новая студия не может быть заведомо более или менее функциональной для скомпилированного приложения, потому что это всего лишь среда разработки, а не API. Если вы нашли решение, оформите его как ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была связана с наличием в строке запрещенных символов и с тем, что строка оказалась слишком длинной. До обновлении студии все было ок